# Mojave App Store is only showing Updates tab

Tags: mac-appstore, mojave

Installed Mojave yesterday - everything is fine except the App Store doesn't show Discover or any of the other tabs - it only shows Updates - see screen grab. The search function works so it's connected fine. I've tried deleting all caches, etc

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, app store shows nothing.

Comment: ...if someone can figure out how to replicate this "problem" on any machine, I would do so on mine! Nice and minimalistic, and I can still search if necessary!

Comment: Same problem here. Thanks for any updates on a fix!

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's just a link to my account info - I'm definitely on the right page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the solution (and origin) to this problem. Thanks @charles for giving me the insight.

The problem occurs because the new Mac App Store app `CFBundleVersion` is marked as 1 so if you have any copy of the old Mac App Store (which had `CFBundleVersion` over 459) in the system, macOS will think is the most recent version and will try to use it on the background.

This is why if you go the the `Apple Logo` > `App Store…` it tries to open the old version.

Deleting the old app bundle from the system resolves the problem.

Comment: how do you delete old bundle CFBundleVersion

Comment: @Buscar웃 You just need to delete the old version of the App Store that you have somewhere in your file system.  Spotlight wasn't pulling it up for me, but I realized I had a backup of an old Macbook on my file system & found the offending App Store app in there.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same issue.
Not really an answer but more diagnostic info:

- MBPro early 2015, 13-inch Retina
- Tried resetting PRAM
- Tried starting up in safe mode
- Tried deselecting all the boxes in the advanced tab of the software update preferences
- Tried launching it from terminal (don't know why I thought that would work)
- Ran
- disk first aid
- **Created a new user account and I could see all the tabs in that account.**

Because the test user was vanilla, I am guessing there is something booting up in the primary account that is causing a conflict. Primary account is an admin and test account is a standard user without admin privileges.

Comment: Just tried another account on my mac and the App Store is working fine, so yeh something must be blocking it

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. I can only see updates in Mojave App Store, but if I open the App Store, 
then follow this with opening the app store from the Apple Logo menu top left, I can also open the old High Sierra App Store which has all the apps .....  It also seems to revert my location back to where I bought the iMac a couple of years ago ...

Comment: Update: I definitely have 2 versions of App Store v2.4 and 3.0. How do I delete one of these as the permissions will not let me remove the old v2.4 per the description from @pvieito. Thanks

Comment: Mines asked for password before moving 2.4 to trash, but it let me do it.