# Mojave App Store Only Shows "Updates" Tab

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, mojave

I'm having trouble with the App Store since installing Mojave. The issue seems to have been addressed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337578/mojave-app-store-is-only-showing-updates-tab/337927), but since I'm new to this site, it won't allow to post there with follow-up questions. I'm not sure how to find/fix the "CFBundleVersion" issue described in that article. Furthermore, when I click Apple > App Store, it opens the current (broken) version, not an older version of the App Store. Any advice for someone who's a novice? Thank you!

Comment: let me give you some points so you can ask follow up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, just figured out an easier way to resolve this:

1. Spotlight > System Information.
2. In the lefthand column, locate Software > Applications.
3. Find "App Store" in the list. If there are two versions, click the older one and identify its location.
4. Navigate to that location in Finder and confirm (via right click > Get Info) that it's the older version. Delete it.

Voila!

Comment: Thank f**k if i could upvote more than once i would, thank you! ❤️

Answer (score 0):

I still have the same problem. I cannot delete the previous version and if I try to drag it to the trash it says "App Store cannot be modified or deleted as it's required by macOS" The old version is in the previous content folder. Any ideas?